# how to output result of group by of two columns with one column values as row and another as columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have table like this

```
id  col1    col2
1   A       1
2   B       0
3   A       1
4   C       1
5   B       0
6   A       0
7   C       1
8   C       1
9   B       1
10  B       0
```

I need a query something like this

```
Values  1   0
A       2   1
B       1   3
C       3   0
```

In the above result the header shows the `col2` distinct values `(1,0)` and rows names represents distinct values of `col1`. The values in the table shows the counts.

Any suggestion to get the result like this in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation :

```
select col1,
       sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 1,
       sum(case when col2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 0
from table t
group by col1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE col2 = 1) AS 1,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE col2 = 0) AS 0,      
FROM 
    foo
GROUP BY 
    col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are simpler ways to write this logic.  The first is Postgres-specific:

```
select col1,
       sum( (col2 = 1)::int ) as num_1,
       sum( (col2 = 0)::int as num_0
from t
group by col1;
```

The second just uses arithmetic:

```
select col1,
       sum( col2 ) as num_1,
       sum( 1 - col2 ) as num_0
from t
group by col1;
```